# Adding and listing an array of structs

Tags: c++, c

I've been having a few problems with using an array of structs and simply listing them and adding to them. I am not really all too sure about what's happening, I've had a search around and asked a few friends and they've suggested that it is something to do with the memory allocation and another has said that memory allocation is not needed and that there is a problem in my code.

I have been unable to locate the problem and was wondering if anyone would be able to point me in the direction of to where I am going wrong.

I apologies if the code doesn't look right - not really sure on how to implement it on the site.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    typedef struct data{
      int testone;
      int testtwo;
    }data;

    struct data _dataStore[25];
    int dataCount = 0;

    int addData(struct data __dataStore[dataCount]){

      printf("\n\t\t\tPacket Source - ");
      scanf("%i", &_dataStore[dataCount].testone);

      printf("\t\t\tPacket Destination - ");
      scanf("%i", &_dataStore[dataCount].testtwo);

      system("CLS");

      return 0;
    }

    void listData(struct data _dataStore[25]){

      int i = 0;

      for (i = 0; i < dataCount; i++){
        printf("data stored - %i",dataCount);
        printf("%i___%i \n",          _dataStore[dataCount].testone,_dataStore[dataCount].testtwo);
      }
    }


    int main(){

      char choice;

      do{
        printf("\t\t\t Counter - %i", dataCount+1);
        printf("\n\t\t\t1 - Add data. \n");
        printf("\t\t\t2 - List data. \n");
        printf("\n\t\t\tEnter your choice - ");

        fflush(stdin); 
        choice = getchar();
        getchar();

        switch(choice){ 
          case '1':
            addData(&_dataStore[dataCount]);
            dataCount++;
            system("CLS");
            break;
          case '2':
            system("CLS");
            listData(&_dataStore[dataCount]);
            break;
          default:
            printf("Invalid input \n");
            break;
        }
      }while (choice != '5');

      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Is it C or C++? `struct`s in those languages are very different beasts.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been a bit more specific - this is in C. I editted my title :).

Comment: function definitions and call are not same. for example `int addData(struct data __dataStore[dataCount])` where argument is just a structure but your code calls it like `addData(&_dataStore[dataCount]);` where argument is address of structure.

Comment: what exactly is the problem you're facing?

Comment: The code clearly shows a few issues.  You should know if it needs memory allocation or not. Otherwise it means you need to study C a bit more. Try, it's fun and nothing gets broken beyond repair :)

Comment: When listing the packets - I am receiving the output of 0__0 instead of what I entered into the array.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few apparent bugs, for example:

```
for (i = 0; i < dataCount; i++){
        printf("data stored - %i",dataCount);
        printf("%i___%i \n",          _dataStore[dataCount].testone,_dataStore[dataCount].testtwo);
      }
     }
```

I suspect you wanted to say `_dataStore[i]` instead.  Also, I suggest using a more sensible function prototype:

```
int addData(struct data*  __dataStore, int arrayLen)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected code which works well for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct data{
    int testone;
    int testtwo;
}data;

struct data _dataStore[25];
int dataCount = 0;

int addData(){

    printf("\n\t\t\tPacket Source - ");
    scanf("%d", &_dataStore[dataCount].testone);

    printf("\t\t\tPacket Destination - ");
    scanf("%d", &_dataStore[dataCount].testtwo);

    system("CLS");

    return 0;
}

void listData(){

    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < dataCount; i++){
        printf("data stored - %d: ",dataCount);
        printf("%d___%d \n",          _dataStore[i].testone,_dataStore[i].testtwo);
    }
 }


int main()
{

    char choice;

    do{
        printf("\t\t\t Counter - %i", dataCount+1);
        printf("\n\t\t\t1 - Add data. \n");
        printf("\t\t\t2 - List data. \n");
        printf("\n\t\t\tEnter your choice - ");

        fflush(stdin);
        choice = getchar();
        getchar();

        switch(choice){


        case '1':
            addData();
            dataCount++;
            system("CLS");
            break;


        case '2':
            system("CLS");
            listData();
            break;

        case '5':
            printf("Will exit...");
            break;

        default:
            printf("Invalid input \n");
            break;
        }
    }while (choice != '5');
    return 0;
}
```

Please pay attention to the following: read / write integers with %d not %i, the index in listData() shall be i not dataCount, I removed the not-needed params of the functions since the variables are global, I added a new case in switch() so that it prints a better message when exiting, not "invalid input".

All variables you are using are statically allocated so you do not need memory allocation.

Comment: Thank you for this. With a program like this - would you suggest using memory allocation?

Comment: @Dannys19  You can use struct pointer instead of struct variable in this.Then you don't have to care about size .

Comment: I'm going to look into malloc and calloc for an array of structs for now just to look into the basics as I have always left this out.

Comment: If you wish, you can allocated memory for variable _dataStore, somewhere at the beginning of main() function and deallocate it at the end of main(). However is up to the programmer in this case to use or not memory allocation. If you are OK with my fixes, you may accept the answer by clicking the tick symbol at the right of the answer.

Comment: One important aspect I saw in your code: you should take care of having the same data type at function declaration and at function call, i.e. both shall be int, or both shall be int[], etc. You had this in your code, but the code was semantically incorrect: here addData(&_dataStore[dataCount]); you are passing an address of the dataCount-th element (zero-indexed) and I am not sure this is what you actually meant.